# Returning clicked element when Delegating instead of Direct using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to return the element clicked (using $(this) for example) when delegating events instead of directly assigning them? In the example below, JS Direct alerts the class of the clicked .test element, while JS Delegating alerts undefined.

HTML

```
<div>
  <button class='test one'>one</button>  
</div>

<div>
  <button class='test two'>two</button>  
</div>
```

JS Direct - (alerts 'test one' or 'test two')

```
$('.test').on('click', function() {

    alert($(this).attr('class'));

});
```

JS Delegating - (alerts 'undefined')

```
$(document).on('click', $('.test'), function() {

    alert($(this).attr('class'));

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the syntax correct.

I'm not sure what jQuery is doing under the hood when you pass it `$('.test')`, but the net effect seems to be "match absolutely everything". Click somewhere that isn't a button, you will still get an alert.

The second argument for `on` should be a **string** containing a **selector**, not a jQuery object.

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
```

… then `this` works as expected.

(It doesn't make any sense to pass a jQuery object since the point of using a delegated selector is to match elements that might not exist when the event handler is bound … and you can't do that if you have to get the elements and wrap them in jQuery before you bind the event!)

Comment: Yea duh, this works. And yea I also noticed that clicking anywhere in the document would call the function, when I only really want the function called when the button is clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your callbacks receive as a parameter the event object that contains the target of the event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

```
$(document).on('click', $('.test'), function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).attr('class'));

});
```

Comment: `event.target` gives the element that actually recieved the click, not the one which the delegation selector matches. It won't actually make a difference when a button is clicked *in this particular example* because the buttons don't have any child elements (such as images or spans). That said, you still have the problem (which the OP didn't mention they had, presumably because they haven't noticed it yet) which is that clicking *anywhere* in the document triggers the alert.